# ccm cannot connect to nodetool, it throws connection refused

Tags: cassandra, jmx, cassandra-2.0, nodetool, ccm

I am using ccm with cassandra 2.0.9. I have 8 nodes virtually in ccm. when i try to connect to node1 status it shows following error

```
rishi@rishi:~/work/ccm$ ccm node1 status
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ccm", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('ccm==2.1.7', 'ccm')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 528, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1401, in run_script
    exec(script_code, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ccm-2.1.7-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/ccm", line 86, in <module>

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/ccmlib/cmds/node_cmds.py", line 257, in run
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/ccmlib/node.py", line 720, in nodetool
ccmlib.node.NodetoolError: Nodetool command '/home/local/rishi/work/ccm/apache-cassandra-2.0.9/bin/nodetool -h localhost -p 7100 status' failed; exit status: 1; stderr: Failed to connect to 'localhost:7100': Connection refused
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: whats output of `ccm status` ?

Comment: `Cluster: 'Reach_Cluster'
----------------------------
node8: UP
node1: UP
node3: UP
node2: UP
node5: UP
node4: UP
node7: UP
node6: UP`